# How to make simple ANOVA in R

Tags: r, cran, anova

I have to make ANOVA in R using build-in packages, my data seems like this :

```
dane=cbind(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

`a` and `b` are variables for which I want to test hypothesis about equality  of means in groups assigned by `c` variable. My case is the simplest case when `t-test` is not enough.

Comment: Searching for "one-way anova r" yielded this: http://ms.mcmaster.ca/peter/s2ma3/s2ma3_0102/classnotes/notes20020326.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dane <- data.frame(dane)
with(dane, aov(c(a[c==1],b[c==2]) ~ c))
```

Or, if you mean to test both `a` and `b` as separate dvs:

```
with(dane, aov(a ~ c))
with(dane, aov(b ~ c))
```